# How do I add dependencies to my sbt file so that I can use apache.commons in my project?

Tags: scala, sbt

With a Scala sbt project, what do I add to the build.sbt file so that the compiler does not complain about the following line in my program?

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution
```

Currently `commons` is highlighted in red in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math3" % "3.6.1"
```